# jQuery - passing input field to hidden input value

Tags: jquery, input, field

Im trying to use the jQuery .change function to get an input field value:

```
    <input type="text" name="qty2" id="qty2" maxlength="12" title="QtyField" class="input-text qty2">
```

to apply it to the value of another field

```
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="" title="Qty" class="input-text qty">
```

So far iver used:

```
     $("#qty2.input-text.qty2").keyup(function(){
    value = $("#qty2.input-text.qty2").val(); 
    $("#qty.input-text.qty").html(value);
});
```

And no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jQuery.change() method cannot "get an input field value."

Excerpt from documentation:
"Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element"

Use `jQuery.val()`.
Here are a couple of options...

```
$('#qty2').bind("keyup", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#qty').val(val);
});
```

See [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBJF9/)

The only drawback with this method, is that it wouldn't actively update until the key is 'UP' so if you hold <kbd>H</kbd> down, then the second box wouldn't be updated until you let the key up.

Alternatively, the `jQuery.change()` does not actively update until the field has left focus. [see this jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBJF9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To change the value of an **input**, you must use **$.val()** instead of **$.html()**.

```
$('#qty2').change(function(){
    $('#qty').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
$("#qty2").change(function(){
    value = $(this).val(); 
    $("#qty").val(value);
});
```

By the way, when you have an ID there's no need to add anything else to your selectors, as IDs are supposed to be unique anyways...

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use **.val()** instead of **.html()**:

```
    $("#qty2").keyup(function(){
    value = $("#qty2").val(); 
    $("#qty").val(value);
    });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YER9b/